# Exchange: New-EmailAddressPolicy Invalid Argument

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365

I'd like to add a email address policy to my office 365 exchange online.
But when I try to add the policy, I always get the same error.

Command:

```
New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name MyPolicy -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates "SMTP:%2g%s@example.com" -Priority 2
```

Output:

```
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-EmailAddressPolicy], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,New-EmailAddressPolicy
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Do you have an idear what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The examples [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/new-emailaddresspolicy?view=exchange-ps) show all the -Name arguments in quotes. Try putting the name for the policy in quotes:

```
New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name "MyPolicy" -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates "SMTP:%2g%s@example.com" -Priority 2
```

Edit:

Aha, the percent sign (`%`) and ampersand (`@`) are special characters in PowerShell. You might have to escape them, even within a string. I would try `"SMTP:\%2\%s\@example.com"`.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error